# Bing Maps Rest service code

Tags: vb.net, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I trying to use Bing Maps REST services with my Windows form application, currently I can get Bing Maps to appear on the screen, but now that I want to add rest service I'm noticing that for some reason VB isn't recognizing some of the code. e.g. Map.CredentialsProvider.GetCredentials()

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside of a function or Sub.